# How to insert one row to each file?

Tags: file, powershell, insert, pipeline

It's quite convenient to use Linux shell to append some content to a file, using pipe line operations and stream operations would do this.

But in PowerShell, the pipeline is used in object level, not in file level. Then, how can I for example, insert a row "helloworld" to a list of files, to become their first line?

Answer (score 2):

It is not that trivial, but you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {$a = Get-Content $_
                     Set-Content $_ -Value "hi", $a}
```

Tho to be honest i do think it matches your definition of a pipeline.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $('hi'; Get-Content $_) | Set-Content $_ }`, or shorter `ls | % { $('hi'; gc $_) | sc $_ }`. It's more or less the same as in a Linux shell.

Comment: Yup even better than a temp variable.

Comment: Beware that even though you don't need an explicit variable you're still reading the entire file into memory before writing it back to disk.